# 1961 3D Radar Chart = How is this replicated today?

Tags: data-visualization

Harvard Anthropologists in the late 1950s studied 5 different communities and created a theory that became the cornerstone of anthropological studies in worldview. They displayed their survey results by use of a unique radar chart that shows combinations of High/Medium/Low values on three different dimensions as appears in the attached charts. Does anyone know what type of chart this is and how that is displayed today using current tools?

The radar charts I have seen have 2 axes = x and y. This has three axes = x, y, z. The vertical axis goes from positive to 0 and then from 0 to negative; the axis that starts in the bottom left goes from positive to 0 and from 0 to negative; and the one that starts in the bottom right goes from positive to 0 and then from 0 to negative. Each point is plotted along all three axes. Charts with x,y,z today usually are 3 dimensional. This diagram is 2D but still has the third dimension. So far I have not figured out how to create a 2 dimensional radar chart using 3 dimensions.

[image: radar-chart plotting combinations of High/Medium/Low valuse on three different dimensions]

Comment: I don't quite understand what those charts are telling us. [Radar charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) are still in common use. The question just is whether they are used in the same way as in this publication (where, as I said, I do not understand the message).

Comment: Radar (polar) charts, very common.

Comment: They seem to have some similarity with ternary plots but without understanding the whole article it is hard to know.

Comment: The radar charts I have seen have 2 axes = x and y. This has three axes = x, y, z. The vertical axis goes from positive to 0 and then from 0 to negative; the axis that starts in the bottom left goes from positive to 0 and from 0 to negative; and the one that starts in the bottom right goes from positive to 0 and then from 0 to negative. Each point is plotted along all three axes. Charts with x,y,z today usually are 3 dimensional. This diagram is 2D but still has the third dimension.

So far I have not figured out how to create a 2 dimensional radar chart using 3 dimensions.

Comment: Can you provide the data / the values of the points being plotted? Radar charts don't just have 2 axes, they can have an arbitrarily large number of axes; follow Stephan Kolassa's link to see.

Comment: -- gung  -- This was published in 1961 - Pre-Digital World. The data was compiled by Anthropologists from Harvard in the 1950s. No, of course, there is no raw dataset to download (data/values of the points being plotted).